# Bootstrap navbar links is not displayin with scripts attached

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a bootstrap based site, I don't know what mistake I have don't I have attached the bootstrap.min.js and jquery at the bottom.  I am not able reduce the font size of the links in media query and when in the hamburger view I click on the icon Nothing shows up. I will add my complete script if JS fiddle, I will attach the navbar code here.
https://jsfiddle.net/kxngo67r/1/ *I dont know how to add bootstrap to jsfiddle*

Its my first paid project and I am messing it up, please tell me how to change the font size and how to make the links display

---

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default clearfix">
            <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class=""><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li> <a href="aboutus.html"><span style="white-space: nowrap">About Us</span></a> </li>
            <li> <a href="whoweare.html"><span style="white-space: nowrap">Who We Are</span></a> </li>
            <li> <a href="mission.html">Mission</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="donate.html">Donate</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="contactus.html"><span style="white-space: nowrap">Contact Us</span></a> </li>

          </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
 nav {
                width: 100%;
                height: 40px;
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(#3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15);
                background: linear-gradient(#3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15, #388813, #3f9a15);
                border-radius: 6px !important;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px !important;
            }

        .nav a{
            color: white !important;
            font-size: 1.5em !important;
        }
```

Comment: Where is your `jsfiddle`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ADDED

Comment: If you change the height of the navbar from it's default min-height of 50px, your navigation (you have it at height: 40px) on mobile will no longer show any background color because it's the navbar that extends when you toggle. Since it's set at only 40px, it can't work. This is why I stated this in your question here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397188/bootstrap-navbar-link-text-breaks-down-in-google-chrome-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: @amguruprasath here is your page with external link on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/v0nakgh2/). Its working perfectly